# Bash variable set at the end of a rake command

Tags: bash, rake

I see this in a script:

```
rake -f some_rake_file raketask1 raketask2 --trace CI_REPORTS=/some/directory
```

CI_REPORTS is a bash shell variable. It's set at the end of the statement on the same line as the rake command. How does that work? I expected to see this:

```
CI_REPORTS=/some/directory
rake -f some_rake_file raketask1 raketask2 --trace
```

(See http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/ci_reporter/ for more about CI_REPORTS)

Comment: `rake` allows you to set an environment variable for the execution of that rake command (http://www.rubyrake.org/user_guide/chapter02.html). You could also do it before calling `rake` which would set it outside of the `rake` execution (and you might have to do `export CI_REPORTS=...` for the `rake` command to see it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following `rakefile`:

```
namespace :bleh do
    task :bar do
        puts ENV['FOO']
    end
end
```

Each of the following will print "hello":

```
rake bleh:bar FOO="hello"
```

This passes `FOO` as a variable to `rake` and it treats it as a shell environment variable. The calling shell doesn't see it as a shell variable, but `rake` will set up its `ENV` structure as if it were. (See [rake documentation](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html)).

```
FOO="hello" rake bleh:bar
```

The shell sets `FOO` as an environment variable only for the execution of `rake`. After the task completes, `FOO` is no longer set in the shell.

```
export FOO="hello"
rake bleh:bar
```

The current shell has `FOO` set to "hello" and the `export` makes it visible to all the current shell's subtasks (subshells).

However, the following will print nothing (blank):

```
FOO="hello"
rake bleh:bar
```

In this case, `FOO` is not visible to `rake` in this context (it hasn't been exported to subtasks).

Comment: Wow, gotta love stackoverflow. Thank you for your clear and complete answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Shells will simply pass it as a parameter, so the 6th parameter is going to be `CI_REPORTS=/some/directory`.

If you want to set an environment variable, change the order:

`CI_REPORTS=/some/directory rake -f some_rake_file raketask1 raketask2 --trace`